# for loop on something else than an object

Tags: javascript

What happens when I try to loop on an int like this:

```
var x = 0;
for (var k in x) {
  // x[k]
}
```

Should I look for unexpected behavior or does it just not enter the loop?
(so far my experiments seem to show that it does not enter the loop... but it could do something I don't see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no methods defined in the vanilla JavaScript Number object prototype. Your code enters the loop (*all* objects in JS can be iterated) but there is nothing to iterate over in this case.

If you would do:

```
Number.prototype.foo = "bar";
```

Your loop body would run once for the `foo` property.

Comment: Actually, [there are methods](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.7.4): `toFixed`, `toPrecision`, etc. but I assume they are not enumerable.

Comment: @Felix: You are right. They also do not show up in the Chrome debugging console (`console.dir(0)` says "no properties").

Comment: Yes I tried the same. I think in this case the value is not converted to an object. `console.dir(new Number(0))` works though (`__proto__` shows contains these methods).

Answer (score 1):

x isn't a collection. What is there for it to iterate through?

Comment: because I'm not he only one to use my code. Very short example:
function f (x) {
  for (var k in x) {
    document.write(x[k] + "<br />");
  }
}
f(0);
f(mycollection);

(sorry for the bad formating)

Comment: @Hugo: That's what documentation is for. If someone passes values to your function that it does not understand: not your problem.

Comment: You're absolutly right.
But you'll agree that getting a better knowledge on how things work cannot harm (thx for your comments, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Only objects can be iterated with the `for in` loop.

So, say you have a variable `a` that holds a reference to something. If `typeof a !== 'object'` then you cannot iterate over your `a` var.

Note that you can iterate over arrays, as arrays are objects too (`alert(typeof [])`).

As for your example, x is not an object, it is a number (`typeof x == 'number'`), so the `for in` will not work; but if you declare your number as a `Number` object :

```
var x = new Number(0);
```

you can loop over its methods since now `typeof x == 'object'`

Comment: I think JavaScript will automatically convert the number to a `Number` object  in this case.